# Python get locals of another function and set them global

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Is it possible to get local variables from another function after calling it and set them global?

Lets say I have something like

```
@setGlobals
def setup():
     width = 600
     height = 400
```

and I want to get those variables and set them global without usign the `global ...`

i know that I could use something like `globals().update(locals())`
inside the function

Or put it to an object and use `self.width and self.height`

But is there a way to have a function like

```
def setGlobals(func):
     def weapper(*args, **kwargs):
           func(...)
           #globals().update(func.locals())


# returns {'width':600, 'height':400}
```

Thanks

Comment: Variables are something that is created when the function is running, and are discarded when they go out of scope. **Those variables don't even exist unless that function is currently executing.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That capability would be fundamentally unreasonable.  Imagine this:

```
def f(x):
  y=x*2

[f(1),f(2)]
getLocals(f)   # is y 2 or 4?
```

The local variable values are an aspect of a *particular call* to a function, not the function itself.

Comment: (The question has been edited significantly since I wrote this.)